# Want to select a column based on a return (within that same column) below a threshold in R

Tags: r, xts, zoo, quantitative-finance

I have a return data frame (xts, zoo object) of size 1379 x 843. It should be read as date x security.

This is an example of the input:

```
            BIIB.US.Equity JNJ.US.Equity BLUE.US.Equity BMRN.US.Equity AGN.US.Equity
2018-06-15   -0.5126407   0.001633853   -0.070558376   0.0846854857  -0.004426559
2018-06-18   -0.052158804  -0.310521165   -0.035226652  -0.0206967213  -0.008430535
2018-06-19    0.010099613   0.010303330    0.006510048   0.0004184976   0.007745167
2018-06-20    0.016504588  -0.004324060    0.029808774   0.0284459318   0.012366368
2018-06-21    0.001616924  -0.004834480    0.023211360   0.0009151922  -0.015411839
2018-06-22   -0.004136679   0.010374640   -0.065652522   0.0097023265   0.005322048
```

Now I would like to return a different list:

```
             BIIB.US.Equity JNJ.US.Equity
2018-06-15   -0.5126407     0.001633853
2018-06-18   -0.052158804  -0.30521165
2018-06-19    0.010099613   0.010303330
2018-06-20    0.016504588  -0.004324060
2018-06-21    0.001616924  -0.004834480
2018-06-22   -0.004136679   0.010374640
```

As you can see the second list only contains 2 columns because there is a dip in 51% on the first security at time 2018-06-15, and a dip in 30% on the second security in the second at time 2018-06-18. Both of which exceed the threshold of 30%

What I want is to get a new data frame from my current which selects securities where there is an instance of a 30% drop in security return or greater.

Currently I have tried:

```
df1 <- returns < -.3
returns[df1]
```

but this returns the error:

```
Error in `[.xts`(returns, df1) : 'i' or 'j' out of range
```

I have also tried this:

```
cls <- sapply(returns, function(c) any(c < -.3))
a<- returns[, cls, with = FALSE]
```

Yet that returns a matrix of the same size, only with a lot of NA values.
Is there something I am missing?

Basically what I'd expect to get out is a data frame "df" of size 1379 x (something less than 843) where df is all columns where there is an instance of a daily drop of -.3 or less.

EDIT:
To those that have tried to help, thank you, but the output returns as such (I assigned the call to a):

```
    > a
     BIIB.US.Equity JNJ.US.Equity BLUE.US.Equity BMRN.US.Equity AGN.US.Equity PFE.US.Equity NBIX.US.Equity
    > summary(a)
         Index   
     Min.   :NA  
     1st Qu.:NA  
     Median :NA  
     Mean   :NA  
     3rd Qu.:NA  
     Max.   :NA  
    > str(a)
    An 'xts' object of zero-width
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df[, sapply(df, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE) <= -0.3)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also returns an "'xts' object of zero-width" that contains only a print out of the security names.

Comment: What happens when you just do `sapply(df, function(x) min(x) <= .3)`  You should get a vector of TRUE/FALSE values.

Comment: I do get a logical vector filled with only NA's [1:843]. I should mention my data has many NA values that I cannot remove for analysis

Comment: That'd do it.  add `na.rm = TRUE` (see edited solution)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure why this was edited - the two versions are fundamentally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide an input/output example I am not sure if I understand you correctly but try

```
df[colSums(df <= -0.3, na.rm = T) > 0]
```

**Edit**

added `na.rm = T` after OPs update

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work, I will try to add an example for the input

Comment: I added an input/output, hopefully that clears things up. EDIT: Also I tried the switch that you made and it still does not work. what it outputs is an 'xts' object of zero-width which holds the security names and no other information

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it should work this way, using package `data.table` :
Let's try with an example data set that contains some NAs.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10)*0.1
y <- x 
z <- rnorm(10)+1 
equities <- data.table(x,y,z)
equities[ sample(1:10,3), x:=NA]
equities[ sample(1:10,2), y:=NA]
equities[ sample(1:10,2), z:=NA]
print(equities)
              x           y          z
 1: -0.06264538 -0.06264538         NA
 2:  0.01836433  0.01836433  1.3898432
 3: -0.08356286 -0.08356286  0.3787594
 4:  0.15952808  0.15952808 -1.2146999
 5:  0.03295078          NA  2.1249309
 6:          NA          NA  0.9550664
 7:          NA  0.04874291  0.9838097
 8:  0.07383247  0.07383247         NA
 9:          NA  0.05757814  1.8212212
10: -0.03053884 -0.03053884  1.5939013
```

Choose the right columns, as described in Melissa's post:

```
myChoice <- sapply(equities, function(x) min(x, na.rm=T) <= -0.3)
```

And eventually:

```
newequities <- equities[ , myChoice , with=F]
print(newequities)
            z
 1:         NA
 2:  1.3898432
 3:  0.3787594
 4: -1.2146999
 5:  2.1249309
 6:  0.9550664
 7:  0.9838097
 8:         NA
 9:  1.8212212
10:  1.5939013
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight addendum to this, because I came back into work today and noticed the answer wasn't quite what I wanted. If you want to select the columns based on the row values, then the answer provided that I marked correct is just missing one comma!

The current answer selects all the rows needed, but for the desired output described in the original post, you must use the command:

```
returns[, sapply(returns, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE) <= -.3)]
```

notice this has a comma in the beginning in order to select the rows.

Hopefully this helps someone else at some point!

Comment: You shouldn't leave the "best answer check mark" on an incorrect/incomplete answer.  That is likely to confuse people who do not read down to your actually correct answer here.  I've edited Melissa Key's answer to reflect your point here.